# TFS 2010 Test results consolelog output not found

Tags: testing, logging, console

I've just install TFS 2010 and associated unit tests written in C# VS2010 with testcases in a test plan in TFS2010.

When I run the tests in visual studio, i'm able to get console.write log output. However, when I run the same test in a test plan in TFS, I can't seem to find the console log. What do I need to do to view the console output of tests run under a test plan.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the logs related to test execution from the Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) attached to the test run/test results and stored to the TFS server. To view the attachments, open the test run (for run-level attachments) or each individual test result (for result-level or result-iteration-level attachments) in MTM. There should be an attachments section on those pages.

Comment: Maybe for failed tests, but what about the passed ones?